# How to authorize in xamarin android via mysql database

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin.android

How to authorize in xamarin android via mysql database?

Here code:

```
MysqlCommand com = new MysqlCommand("SELECT test_log, test_pass FROM login WHERE test_log =@log AND test_pass =@pass", mycon);
    mycon.Open();
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log", login1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password1.Text);
    MySqlReader dr = com.ExcecuteReader();
```

download all links and connected MysqlClient. please need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to authorize in xamarin android via mysql database?

I don't know what library are you currently using, but you can have a try of [MySQL Plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/mysql-plugin). You can add it to your project through `Component->Edit Components-> Get More Components->Search MySQL Plugin on the search bar`.

And then you can access MySQL using following codes:

```
public bool loginFromMySQL()
{
    MySqlConnection sqlconn=null;
    bool loginSuccess=false;
    try
    {
        string connsqlstring = "Server=serverAddress;Port=3306;database=database Name;User Id=userName;Password=user password;charset=utf8";
        sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connsqlstring);
        sqlconn.Open();

        DataSet tickets = new DataSet();
        string userName = "userName";
        string password = "password";
        string queryString = "select * from  login where userName='" + userName + "' and password='" + password + "'";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(queryString, sqlconn);
        adapter.Fill(tickets, "login");
        if (tickets.Tables["login"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //login success
            loginSuccess=true;
        }
        else
        {
                loginSuccess=false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }
    sqlconn.Close();
    return loginSuccess;
}
```